# Custom-control Custom-label "for" attribute placement

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to add a label to the top of these stacked radios. This method works, but I'm returning a warning when I run this through validator.w3.org

The warning states "The for attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form control." This error is popping up because I have the id field in the incorrect location, but I'm unsure as to where it is supposed to be located. I've tried several solutions, but all have returned the same attribute warning.

```html
<div class="col">
    <div class="custom-controls-stacked">
        <label for="gender"> Gender </label>
        <label class="custom-control custom-radio" id="gender">
            <input id="radioStacked3" name="radio-stacked" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="custom-control-description"> Male </span>
        </label>
        <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input id="radioStacked4" name="radio-stacked" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="custom-control-description"> Female </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `for` refers to the `id` of specific `input`. So put an `id` on your input

Comment: You can remove the `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `<label>` for a `<label>` which is a bit weird. The `<label>` is for a form element only.

I would remove the "Gender" label, wrap the whole thing in a `<fieldset>` and put "Gender" into a `<legend>`.